# Setting up Git Repo Recent Check-ins with SharePoint

Tags: git, sharepoint, web-parts

I'm trying to connect a **Recent Checkins** web part in SharePoint to my tfs 2013 hosted git repo. For **Version Control Path** I tried:

```
/repoName
```

resulting in, TF10125: The path "/repoName" must start with $/ , and:

```
$/repoName
$/_git/repoName
$/collectionName/repoName
$/collectionName/pathToRepo/_git/repoName
```

all resulting in, "$/somePath" was not found in source control at version T.